# mvc paging inside an html form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to create paging inside html form.
How do I make each page button change the model's `CurrentPage` property?

I'm new to MVC, so bear with me please.
I have a list of reports that I need to display in a view named `Search`. I made a model for that (`ReportViewModel`), and another model that holds a list of those, named `SearchViewModel`. In `SearchViewModel` I have some other variables like `SearchName`, `SearchDate`, `CurrentPage`, `PageCount`, `PageSize`, etc. The goal is to do paging and searching in one action named `Search` in `ReportsController`.

Now, I would like to keep that action simple by giving that function only `SearchViewModel` instance as a parameter, so that inside I use all variables of that model. Doing that, I won't have to type parameter names twice (once in `SearchViewModel` and once as parameters in `Search` action). I will not need that search function elsewhere, so it's ok for it to not have any parameters other than `SearchViewModel` instance.

So, very loosely, it looks something like this:

**ReportsController.cs**

```
public class ReportsController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Search(SearchViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View(model);

        // do search magic here

        return View(model)
    }
}
```

**Search.cshtml**

```
@model ISFinReports.Models.SearchViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "List";
    Layout = "~/Views/_masterLayout.cshtml";
}
<link href="~/CSS/Search.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/Search.js"></script>


@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Reports", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <div id="divSearchBar">
        // add @Html.DropDownListFor, @Html.TextBoxFor and submit button here
    </div>

    <div id="divReportsTable">
        <table id="tblReports">
            @if (Model.Reports != null)
            {
                foreach (var r in Model.Reports)
                {
                    // add tr, td of all reports in report list
                }
            }
        </table>
    </div>

    <div style="text-align:center">
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.PageCount; i++)
        {
            @Html.ActionLink(i.ToString(), "Search", "Reports", new { CurrentPage = i });
            // or
            // <input type="submit" value="@i" onClick="meybe something like this?" />
        }
        Current Page @Html.EditorFor(q => q.CurrentPage), of total @Model.PageCount pages
    </div>
}
```

I know that I can simply type twice all the data I need to flow between controller and view, once in model and once as `Search` action parameters, but that's extactly what I'm trying not to do. Currently I have a `textbox` for editing the current page, and it works, because it's created via @Html.EditorFor, but I'd like to have multiple buttons for each page.

I could maybe create a `hidden` field in that form, and create a javascript function that'll find that `hidden` field by id, and change it's `value`, and then call whatever the submit button `onClick` function is. **BUT**, is there a better/shorter/more-MVC way to implement that?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application - More info here: http://devproconnections.com/aspnet-mvc/aspnet-mvc-paging-done-perfectly

Comment: I've read that, and it helped me to understand that paging is simply a part of a search query. Thank you for the link. I would still like to make my own paging system, without nuGet packages